# Firebase - Retrieving Node using 'Node-Id'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having difficulties understanding how to use where while retrieving a full node. If I have a structure like:

```
- users
   -user_id1
      - key1:value1
      - key2:value2
   -user_id2
      - key1:value3
      - key2:value4
  ...
```

If I know "user_id1", how can I get the whole node; so I can use `snapshot.key` to get the user_id, and use `snapshot.value` to get as `[key:value]`?

```
   -user_id1
      - key1:value1
      - key2:value2
```

This is what I tried so far...

```
let key = "user_id1"   // static for test

let usersRef = Firebase(url: secret + "/users")
usersRef.queryEqualToValue(key).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

       print(snapshot)

//     print(snapshot.key)   // id
//     print(snapshot.value) // [key:value]                  
})
```

This is returning:

> `Snap (users) <null>`
>
> `Snap (users) <null>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than what you're trying:

```
ref.child("users").child("user_id1").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print(item.key)
    print(item.value)
})
```

This is not just simpler, it's also cheaper for the database, since it doesn't have to perform a (potentially expensive) query.

For an example, see this section of the [documentation on reading child value with Swift](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#read_data_once).

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I have been using both in testing and wasn't sure when I should use this direct reference vs the query method. Do you have any comments on when to use one or the other ?

Comment: Yup. Yours works too. But if you have a chance, replace it with a simple `child()` call, it'll scale better.

Comment: Thanks Puff - much cleaner as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `queryOrderedByKey()`

For example

```
let ref = root.child("users")

ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqualToValue("user_id1").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    // could get many items in snapshot hence the loop

    for item in snapshot.children {
        print(item)
    }

})
```